# Nicer visual formatting for sqlite3 tables?

Tags: sqlite

How do I format table output in sqlite? For example, if the default behavior for showing entries is hard to read when one of the columns has variable length text. If I do `select a,b,c from table` I get

```
a1|b1|c1
a2|b2|c2
```

while I want some nicer and easily readible formatting like..

```
++++++++++++++++
| a1 | b1 | c1 |
| a2 | b2 | c2 |
++++++++++++++++
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the dot.commands ".mode columns / .width"

```
sqlite3 test.db <<SQL
.mode columns
.width 3 10 10 4
select  'ABCDEFGHIJKLM','ABCDEFGHIJKLM','ABC','ABCDEFGHIJKLM';
SQL
```

will receive
    ABC  ABCDEFGHIJ  ABC         ABCD
but with no other formatings like borders etc, so very rudimentary

ant

Answer (score 3):

For sqlite3 you just need a command
`.mode table`
and your tables should look like this:

```
+----------+-----------+
|  per_id  | per2_id   |
+----------+-----------+
| 13449958 | 5135490   |
| 21085892 | 5135490   |
| 3291872  | 5135490   |
+----------+-----------+
```

In the case you want this to be permanent change, you need to write the same command `.mode table` in the file called .sqliterc (if it doesn't exist just make one) in your home directory.
And that should do it.

Comment: Thank you, especially for the `~/.sqliterc` part. Saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: `.mode box` works quite good as well